# How to check whether this belongs to which list

Tags: python, string, list, validation, python-3.x

I am asking how to check to which list belongs user input. Scenario: I have 2 lists, one for vowels and one for constants, the user inputs a letter to know whether it is a Vowel of Constant, however I don't know how to check whether it is that or that (validation).

```
vowels = ['A','E','I'] # First list
constants = ['B','C','D'] # Second List

userinput = input('Type in letter which you want to check to whether it is a vowel or constant: ') # User types in the letter Which he wants to know to which category does it belong
```

Comment: [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in)

Answer (score 1):

```
if userinput in vowels:
   # it's a vowel
   ...
elif userinput in consonants:
   # it's a consonant
   ...
else:
   # it's neither
   ...
```